# How to remove form underneath video-js player on canvas?

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-canvas, video.js

I'm using VideoJS library, but keep seeing a form below my video player. Does anyone know how to change the configurations to remove this from the canvas?

[image: Screenshot of non working player styling]

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you do not have the video-js stylesheet loaded and thus the browser falls back to the default styling of these elements, to maintain functionality. Taken from their docs - and assming you are using the latest video-js, add this to your page's `head` element, or into your CSS bundling pipeline, if you are using one

```
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```